# IE11 Javascript error undefined null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a javascript error raised in IE11 that is disabling scrolling by mouse on the page. I'd like to know what the problem is with the code and if it can easily be modified to fix it.

The error is:
{exception} Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

It occurs in this block of code, in line 8 as shown handlers is a null reference:

```
return {
        add: function(elem, event, handler) {
            if(!elem.events) {
                elem.events = {};
                elem.handle = function(e) {
                    var ret, handlers = elem.events[e.type];
                    e = fixEvent(e);
                    for(var i = 0, len = handlers.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if(handlers[i]) {
                            ret = handlers[i].call(elem, e);
                            if(ret === false) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                e.stopPropagaton();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            if(!elem.events[event]) {
                elem.events[event] = [];
                if(elem.addEventListener) elem.addEventListener(event, elem.handle, false);
                else if(elem.attachEvent) elem.attachEvent('on'+event, elem.handle);
            }
            elem.events[event].push(handler);
        },
        remove: function(elem, event, handler) {
            var handlers = elem.events[event];
            for(var i = handlers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(handlers[i] === handler) {
                    handlers.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
            if(!handlers.length) {
                delete elem.events[event];
                if(elem.removeEventListener) elem.removeEventListener(event, elem.handle, false);
                else if(elem.detachEvent) elem.detachEvent('on'+event, elem.handle);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: It's telling you that the result of  `handlers = elem.events[e.type]` is that the value of *handlers* is undefined.

Comment: @InvernoMuto - perhaps you would point out what the typo was?

Comment: Thanks all, I just added a condition to only execute that loop if (handlers) and the problem has magically disappeared. Page scrolls in IE11 again.

Comment: Do you have the full block of code that you changed?